# spring's binstubs are overriden after `bundle`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm working on a Rails 3 application using spring. I did a `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to use spring in my bins. When I do a `bundle`, all bins are overriden and I have to redo them with spring.

Is there a way to always keep the springs bins ?